# Titlingpage use in memoir class

Tags: memoir, titles

Why the `titlingpage` command do not function as the titlepage command? is not the same command but for the memoir class?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{titlingpage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

This is covered explicitly in the [`memoir` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (chapter **Four: Titles**, p 61):

> When one of the standard classes is used with the `titlepage` option, `\maketitle` puts the
>   title elements on an unnumbered page and then starts a new page numbered page 1. The
>   standard classes also provide a `titlepage` environment which starts a new unnumbered
>   page and at the end starts a new page numbered 1. You are entirely responsible for specifying exactly what and where is to go on this title page. If `\maketitle` is used within the `titlepage` environment it will start yet another page.
>
> This class provides neither a `titlepage` option nor a `titlepage` environment; instead
>   it provides the `titlingpage` environment which falls between the `titlepage` option and
>   the `titlepage` environment. Within the `titlingpage` environment you can use the
>   `\maketitle` command, and any others you wish. The `titlingpage` pagestyle is used, and
>   at the end it starts another ordinary page numbered one. The `titlingpage` pagestyle is initially defined to be the same as the `empty` pagestyle.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i have just now solved:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{chngpage,calc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
\changetext{}{}{}{((\paperwidth - \textwidth) / 2) - \oddsidemargin - \hoffset - 1in}{}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{titlingpage}
\end{document}
```